# Using Route53 to update DNS with boto. Should I use A name or CNAME and what TTL to use

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dns

Background.  I am using boto and route53 and aws to updade domain subsomanin names of private ip address.  I assign redis masters and slaves to the domains e.g.

```
master.test.com private ip 111.111.111.111
slave.test.com  private ip 222.222.222.222
```

If the master or slave goes down I have logic that will boot a new machine and assign that new machine with either the master or slave subdomain.

I need to ensure that dns are propagated as fast as possible to the extent that  can control.  I am my no means an expert on DNS.  TTL is 60.

As of now, I am using an A record.  In boto it looks like this

```
change = changes.add_change("CREATE","slave.test.com", "A", 60)
change.add_value("222.222.222.222")
```

I can also use a CNAME of the private DNS e.g.

```
    change = changes.add_change("CREATE",slave.test.com, "CNAME", 60)
    change.add_value("ec2_internal_dns")
```

So, my question is this. Does it matter which one I set?  The cname or the A record? I assume that only one can be set.  What is the optimal ttl?  What else am I missing?

Why the difference?  Again, this is not for a public website so I assume to caching issues.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the two members of the `master.test.com` cluster are `1.1.1.1` and `1.1.1.2` and each of these also have A records set up as `numberone.test.com` and `numbertwo.test.com`. If I understand correctly, you are asking whether you should:

1. Point `master.test.com` as A record to `1.1.1.1`, and switch it to `1.1.1.2` if the first server goes down.
2. Point `master.test.com` as CNAME record to `numberone.test.com` and switch it to `numbertwo.test.com` if the first server goes down.

Functionally they are equivalent. Note that `master.test.com` itself should have a short TTL, but the `numberone` and `numbertwo` A records can have a longer TTL because those IP addresses never change.

For performance, there is a *slight* advantage to using A record. Suppose server one just went down and you have switched to server two. With CNAME records, the recursive DNS server you are using probably doesn’t have `numbertwo.test.com` in its cache, so it needs to an extra lookup. This might take tens of milliseconds, which you could save if `master.test.com` were just an A record.

On the other hand a few tens of milliseconds is very little compared to the up to 60 second downtime you could experience simply because of the TTL on `master.test.com`.

If you control every aspect of the system, both clients and servers, you could also consider other solutions for propagating information about which redis server to use, for example with [Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) or the simpler [doozerd](https://github.com/ha/doozerd), which claim to provide near-instant notification of a server going down.